# Передать BluetoothSocket

Tags: android, android-service, android-bluetooth

Столкнулся с проблемой передачи BluetoothSocket.

Моя задача: при подключении сохранить сокет для постоянного прослушивания InputStream в Service.

Мои действия:

1. Создание вспомогательного класса (код ниже прекрасно работает в других Activity):

   ```
   import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;  
   class Game {
       private static Game game = new Game();
       private BluetoothSocket socket = null;
       public static Game getInstance() {
           return game;
       };
       public void setBluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket sock) {
           socket = sock;
       };
       public BluetoothSocket getBluetoothSocket() {
           return socket;
       };
   }
   ```
2. Взятие сокета из вспомогательного класса и входного потока этого сокета:

   ```
   Game game = Game.getInstance();
   game.getBluetoothSocket().getInputStream();
   ```

С помощью альтернативы логов (Toast и BroadcastReceiver) я выяснил, что моя служба не берёт данные из вспомогательного класса.
Чтобы проверить этого, я добавил в класс контекст главной активности (при запуске активность добавляла туда свой контекст: в службе он был равен null, в активностях - не null).

Мои вопросы:

1. Как мне получить сокет в службе?
2. Как мне правильно организовать службу для постоянного отслеживания состояния входного потока?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблема была в манифесте, где я эту службу объявлял.
Я считал, чтобы служба работала и после завершения активности, вызвавшей её, необходимо этой службе выделить отдельный процесс.
Но именно выделение службы в отдельный процесс и мешало ей взаимодействовать с другими классами правильно.
Итог: если хотите использовать значения изменяемых в ходе работы переменных в службе - не надо указывать в манифесте для неё отдельный процесс